# fs Module is Undefined in Node?

Tags: node.js, fs

**Stupid Variable Declaration Mistake - Please Do Not Answer**

I'm running throught [learnyounode](https://github.com/workshopper/learnyounode), and in text #6 - MAKE IT MODULAR, I'm encountering a repeating error:

```
sh-3.2# learnyounode verify program.js
/Users/Tom/Desktop/learnyounode/modules/module.js:7
    fs.readdir(dir, function(err, data){
       ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Here's the bit of my code that does that:

```
var fs = require('fs'); 
fs.readdir(dir, function(err, data){
   #SOME OTHER STUFF
}
```

Disregarding the rest of the code - how is `readdir` not a method of fs? It's a default one, no?

Comment: What version of node do you use? `node -v`

Comment: you show `fs.readdir` but the error is about `fs.readdirSync`... Are you sure you post the correct code? Also post the rest of the code, looks like you override fs with another object

Comment: @MichaelMalura v0.12.2

Comment: try `console.log(fs)` after importing. Maybe this gives you some hint about what is happening

Comment: Damn I feel dumb sometimes. Declared fs twice.

Comment: this happens, at least it works now :) good luck!